# Hoping to identify a stamp on a bronze that I have

Tags: character-identification

[image]I am hoping someone can help me identify the stamp on what I believe is a Chinese bronze crab.[image]

Comment: This may not be a word, but a symbol of design. Just like the Mercedes-Benz trademark, it only indicates which manufacturer produced it.

Comment: I can make out a 師. Is this supposed to be an antiquity or something?